# How should Minecraft Java Edition command questions be answered concerning versions?

Tags: discussion, minecraft, site-policies, game-versions

## Issue

How should versions for Minecraft Java Edition be handled?
The [current agreement](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13401/28182), concluded at the time of 1.13, is that the answer should have separated areas or multiple answers.
The issue for the first separated option is that now and especially in the future, things like this can happen:

> #### 1.17
>
> Lorem ipsum
>
> #### 1.15-1.16
>
> In 1.15 and 1.16 the `foo` tag was known as `bar`
>
> #### 1.13-1.14
>
> Here is the workaround for 1.14 (Versions below 1.13 have a different syntax).

---

That was a bit of an exaggeration but you see the point.
But for the latter, having 4 different answers for different versions is just inconvenient, goes against the site's design, and just has a lot of general flaws.

The only other real way to deal with this is to have multiple questions.

While right now it is not too much of an issue, in the future this will especially become apparent as many things are getting changed such as renaming things, removing things, adding things, and syntax changes. Every other version seems to break and change a lot of things.
Does everyone still have the same idea as a few years ago, or anyone think different? The problem originally arose from [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/367625/258509), which had a bounty put on it for an updated answer. How should these situations be handled?

Comment: As noted by galacticninja, this is a very old point of discussion: [What do we do with questions about games that can no longer be played?](/q/5565), [What should be done with out of version questions?](/q/5727), [What do we do with historic questions that no longer make sense?](/q/7235), [Questions about new game versions](/q/13401) , [Dealing with old questions about non-existent features?](/q/14661)

Comment: I do not know anything about Minecraft versions, but for games I play like say Skyrim/Fallout all support sites/forums/mod sites ask for the latest versions. Is there a reason people do not upgrade to the latest version for Minecraft?

Comment: @LoreFriendly yes like half of the community plays 1.8, a good chunk plays 1.12 and then the rest play the latest version 1.16. 1.13+ just got really garbage for servers and 1.8 and 1.7 are used for PVP

Comment: @Penguin Not nearly "half of the community", just a few people who prefer the 1.8 spam-clicking combat for some reason and not even all of them. But there are actually many reasons why people play older versions, including adventure maps that contain command systems for older versions, nostalgia, system support (for example no OpenGL 4 on Android, which is needed for MC 1.13+), wanting to exploit bugs that got fixed since then, …

Comment: @FabianRöling yes anyone who plays competitive plays 1.7/1.8 which is a massive chunk of the community, almost like half of people who play java do use 1.8 for servers not to mention most servers run on 1.12- bc 1.13+ is garbage for servers

Comment: According to this website it's about 5.6%: https://minecraft-statistic.net/en/global_statistic.html That is not at all "half of the community". And among those that play PVP, only a small subsection doesn't accept the new system, the rest prefers a system in which not the person with the best ping always wins or the person with an autoclicker.

Comment: @FabianRöling no, everyone who plays competitive PVP plays 1.7/1.8 and this is supported by most PVP clients being 1.8. Also this "minecraft-statistic" doesn't have access to the mojang authentication servers so it doesn't know every time someone launches 1.7/1.8. If you believe that is truly reliable information, I am interested to hear how that data is collected? Edit: I just looked around on there and that information is 100% unreliable in the server section Mineplex is listed at 2k players each and being counted multiple times

Comment: @FabianRöling any way why does that matter? I was simply trying to convey that a good chunk of the community doesn't use updated Minecraft, which it doesn't and saying that like 95% of the community uses 1.16 is just not accurate

Comment: @Penguin there are *no* numbers to support either view. A "good chunk is" just as wrong as 5.6%. The stats only show servers, not population. Personally I know nobody playing on 1.8 and be done with it. In fact, a lot of people simply switch versions every now and then. And anyone playing on a cracked server or client is a 0 in the stats anyway and should be disregarded here as well.

Comment: @dly yeah that’s kinda why I’m asking why it matters. People play on different versions, how many do isn’t very relevant is it?

Comment: Okay let’s just stop talking about how many people play x version because its all just anecdotal (i.e. I mostly know/associate with people and groups that play 1.8 and I guess you guys don’t) and the only statistical information brought up was (no offense) unreliable garbage statistics. This isn’t relevant anyway, and is veering farther off from the question at hand.

Comment: @Penguin IMHO it does not matter how many people still play old versions as long as they do. And back to topic: I'd go for multiple answers, unless the question is specifically about one version. I see no point in answering with other versions not asked there.

Comment: There was more discussion elsewhere about my source and it does indeed seem unreliable. There's one for (most) Bukkit servers [here](https://bstats.org/global/bukkit), but not for general Minecraft.

Comment: @dly the one problem I see with multiple answers: Most people just look at the accepted answer or the most upvoted one. You also can't accept multiple answers, so in general having multiple answers for different things is just kind of off of the sites design imo. Also I do agree that multiple versions don't need to be included unless asked for, but I wouldn't oppose if someone were to includes solutions for multiple versions just for the sake of it as its only more useful information to more people

Comment: @Penguin it's either multiple answers or multiple questions. Editing multiple solutions into one answers is against SE's policy as well (unless it's a community wiki answer) as it would deviate from the author's intent. A 1.16 specific solution does not fit into a 1.8 Q&A.

Comment: @dly of course you shouldn't do that to other people's answers, but that also begs the question **why** is it against the rules for your own answer to do it if it includes the answer asked and then additionally another version under another heading?

Comment: @Penguin for your own answer it depends on the question. In most cases it's just noise for the asker. They ask about one problem and want answers for this very problem. Different solutions for each version may be helpful for future readers, but not for the asker.

Comment: @dly As a note, questions are not for the asker, they are for everyone having the same issue.